# How do you take the value of keys and add it to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following libraries in one whole library:

```
sample_collection = {
                    "test1.txt": {"apple": 1, "banana": 1, "lemon": 1},
                    "test2.txt": {"apple": 1, "lemon": 2},
                    }
```

How would I be able to extract these values and it into a list like the following?

```
sample_collection = 

[['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt'],
['apple', 1, 1],
['banana', 1, 0],
['lemon', 1, 2]]
```

I was working on the following, but I am lost as to how I should take the values:

```
for key in sample_collection:
    for key in range(1,len(sample_collection)):
        terms_list.append(sample_collection)
```

A suggestion for a step in the right direction would help immensely :)

Comment: Isn't `['apple', 1, 1]` and `['banana', 1, 0]` what you want?

Comment: You're right, good eye! I have edited the post

Comment: @Lana_Del_Neigh will the nested dictonary have dynamic depth, or will it always be the same (2 in your case)?

Comment: It will be supposed to have a dynamic depth, the actual collection is far bigger. Both for txt collections and keywords

Comment: You say values but I'm also seeing keys in your expected output. Perhaps you could explain what and or why you are trying to accomplish this. It looks like you're looking for a count of occurrences of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can take all fruit names into a variable `value`, you can do something like this:

```
sample_collection = {'test1.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'lemon': 1}, 'test2.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 2}}

temp = [''] + list(sample_collection)
values = list(sample_collection['test1.txt'])
# Assuming this resolves all fruit names into 'values'

res = [temp] + [[x] + [v.get(x, 0) for v in sample_collection.values()] for x in values]

print(res)
# [['', 'test1.txt', 'test2.txt'], ['apple', 1, 1], ['banana', 1, 0], ['lemon', 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you! How would this change if I had wanted to collect values from multiple text files, would it be too different?

Comment: You can use `>>> from itertools import chain >>>  values = set(chain.from_iterable([x.keys() for x in sample_collection.values()]))`. Note that you cannot guarantee order of fruits here as we are using set to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care about adding a new dependency, `pandas` can help you get where you want.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'test1.txt': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'lemon': 1}, 'test2.txt': {'apple': 1, 'lemon': 2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

where:

```
>>> df
        test1.txt  test2.txt
apple           1        1.0
banana          1        NaN
lemon           1        2.0

>>> df.index
Index(['apple', 'banana', 'lemon'], dtype='object')

>>> df.values
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1., nan],
       [ 1.,  2.]])

>>> df.columns
Index(['test1.txt', 'test2.txt'], dtype='object')
```

---

In case you want to do it manually, I would first collect the 'columns', 'indices' and 'values', similarly to what pandas do:

```
columns = []
index_values = {}
for column in data:
    columns.append(column)

    for index in data[column]:
        if index not in index_values:
            index_values[index] = []

        index_values[index].append(data[column][index])

# Then, transform the collected data as you want
data_matrix = [[''] + columns]

for index in index_values:
    data_matrix.append([index] + index_values[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

otherwise something like this should work:

```
fruits = set()
for col in sample_collection.values():
    fruits |= set(col.keys())

res = [['']] + [[fruit] for fruit in fruits]

for col_key, col_data in sample_collection.items():
    res[0].append(col_key)
    for index, fruit in enumerate(fruits):
        res[index+1].append(col_data.get(fruit, 0))
```

the fruits will not be sorted though, I dont know if its an issue.
if so you can just sort fruits before using it